# What is the best source to learn DirectX technology

Tags: directx

I am a Computer Engineer. I wanted to learn DirectX. My question is what is the good source or book to learn DirectX from scratch. What is the prerequisite for it and is proficiency in Component Object Model necessary to learn DirectX.
-Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified if you want to use C/C++ or some .NET language like VB or C#.

If you are wanting to use C++, my recommendation is to start with the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). See also [Getting Started with Direct3D 11](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11/).

If you want to use managed languages, then [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) are a reasonable place to start.

Direct3D is "COM lite". It basically makes use of `IUnknown` for reference counting, and a few aspects make use the polymorphism of `QueryInterface`, but basically everything you'd ever need to do with COM is well-handled with the [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) smart-pointer (at least in C++).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Right now I am planning to start the work for DirectX in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

First download the DirectX SDK and play with the samples, read the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476080(v=vs.85).aspx).... Read the MSDN docs all the time because I'm always finding tid bits that help along the way.

Download the Nvida samples and check out AMD's [gpuopen.com](http://gpuopen.com)

Read Funks Luna's books you can find them [here](http://d3dcoder.net/)

But most of all just start playing with some code, get your feet wet and jump in.
Its taken 2 years for me to get really good with DirectX 11 after coming from XNA with no programing experience so it was a hard road for me but you are a Computer Engineer so I'm sure you will pick it up faster then me.

Find something u want to do, an idea that makes you feel all warm and fuzzy so you have the drive to keep going with it.

as for prerequisite\proficiency I use SharpDX so its a bit different in the C++.

Comment: The DirectX SDK is deprecated. You can use it with a number of caveats, but you shouldn't. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). Frank's book is good, but it predates the deprecation of the legacy DirectX SDK so it's outdated w.r.t. to the details on utility code. See [Book Recommendations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) for some notes.

Comment: But here is the thing about the SDK its one of the best places to see how its all done, I don't use the code directly but I look at how some of the things are done, I do the same with Franks books. I use SharpDX so its even more different for me. If you ask me the SDK is filled with useful stuff. I based my dynamic cube mapper off the SDK code. I even had to write my own wrapper for the new dx math lib so I could use there cube map to Spherical Harmonic path.

Comment: The legacy DirectX SDK was filled with useful stuff, which is why I've been working for 6 years to get the best stuff out of the legacy DirectX SDK and into a form that is useful with just the Windows 8 SDK/Windows 10 SDK. And [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) is only in the Windows 8 SDK/Windows 10 SDK, the legacy DirectX SDK has the older XNAMath.

Comment: Shit I didn't click.... Its Chuck! I have read all your stuff, well most of it and love that new math lib, folded it into my native lib that I use for some stuff sharpDX cant do. Thanks for all the hard work!! I always forget about the newer legacy free samples as I just have the old SDK in a folder that I chew on from time to time. This may sound silly but you should make a new sample browser because that thing just makes checking stuff out easy.